# finding an nth term from complex recurrence relations

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

For simple recurrence relations like, $t_{n} = t_{n-1} + 3$ where $t_0$ is 1 gives the nth term $t_n = 3n + 1$ where $n\geq0$

Or $t_n = xt_{n-1}$ where $t_0 = a$ the nth term is $t_n = ax^n$ where $n\geq0$

how do any of these rules scale up to finding the nth term for more complicated relations like:

$t_n = n^2T_{n-1}$ where $n\geq0$

or a non-linear expressions like:

$t_n = \frac{n^3}{n+2}t_{n-1}$ where $n\geq0$

Answer (score 0):

- If one has a relation of the type $$ t_n = a_n\cdot t_{n-1}, \qquad
     n=1,2,\cdots, $$ one may in general just deduce that $$
     \frac{t_n}{\prod_{k=1}^na_k} = \frac{t_{n-1}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k},
     \qquad n=1,2,\cdots, \tag1 $$ leading to the relation  $$
     u_n=u_{n-1}, \qquad n=1,2,\cdots, \tag2 $$ with $\displaystyle
     u_n=\frac{t_n}{\prod_{k=1}^na_k}$, the relation $(2)$ is then easier
  to evaluate.
- Observe that applying it to the particular sequences given in your
  question, one gets $$ \begin{align} t_n &= n^2 \times t_{n-1} 
     &\text{leads to} \quad  &t_n= c_0 \times (n!)^2 \\ t_n &=
     \frac{n^3}{n+2} \times t_{n-1} &\text{leads to} \quad  &t_n= c_1
     \times \frac{(n!)^2}{(n+1)(n+2)} \end{align} $$ where $c_0,c_1$ are
  arbitrary constants.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I'm struggling to understand the notation. I assume that by $t_n = a_n\cdot t_{n-1}$ you mean that a is where you have anything multiplied by the previous term. but what is the subscript n for? Is it to do with the fact that it matches $t_n$? in this line $\frac{t_n}{\prod_{k=1}^na_k} = \frac{t_{n-1}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k}$ where does the $a_n$ go to? and then where does the $u$ come from?

Comment: thanks for updating with the examples i gave too, is there any chance you could show step-by-step how you got to the answer please?

Comment: @user6817585 You are welcome. "...where does the $a_n$ go to?" Here: $\frac{a_n}{\prod_{k=1}^na_k} = \frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k}.$ Do you see it?

Comment: Observe that if $a_n=n^2$ then $\prod_{k=1}^n a_k=\prod_{k=1}^n k^2=\left( \prod_{k=1}^n k \right)^2=(n!)^2.$ This is your first example.

Comment: ah so it cancels, so by $a_n$ you mean that if $a$ is a function of $n$ ( $f(n)$ ) you substitute $n$ into it. so for the first example in the question $a_1$ would be $1^2$? and for the last example would $a_2$ be $\frac{2^3}{2+2} = \frac{8}{4} = 2$?

Comment: so to get the first line you divide both LHS and RHS by the same thing to cancel out $a_n$ on the RHS

Comment: how does this lead to the relation: (2)?

$u_n=u_{n-1}, \qquad n=1,2,\cdots$